# Django django-two-factor-auth Error 'two_factor_tags' is not a registered tag library

Tags: python, django, django-two-factor-auth

I needed 2FA for my Staff members so I installed [django-two-factor-auth](https://github.com/jazzband/django-two-factor-auth)

But there seems to be an issue with the 'two_factor_tags' in core/login.html file

Error message :

```
'two_factor_tags' is not a registered tag library
. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_urls
cache
crispy_forms_field
crispy_forms_filters
crispy_forms_tags
crispy_forms_utils
example
i18n
l10n
log
static
tz
```

installed apps :

```
# 2fa
'django_otp',
'django_otp.plugins.otp_static',
'django_otp.plugins.otp_totp',
# 'django_otp.plugins.otp_email',  # <- if you want email capability.
'two_factor',
```

Using :

```
Django==4.1
django-otp==1.1.3
django-phonenumber-field==6.4.0
django-two-factor-auth==1.14.0
phonenumbers==8.12.54
```

Any help is much appreciated.
I did remove the tag from the code but it might bug my entire login system.

Comment: Have you added it to `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Yes, updated OP

Comment: maybe helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40686201/django-1-10-1-my-templatetag-is-not-a-registered-tag-library-must-be-one-of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Amrez I got it working, I added "templatetags" folder which contains "two_factor_tags.py & **init**.py" in my "accounts" app's root directory now it works.